# I'm getting 'AttributeError' whenever I try to edit any entry through forms in Django

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Every time I try to edit any entry through a form, it gives Attribute Error.
I have only one model that is BlogPost
**models.py**

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.

class BlogPost(models.Model):
    """ A title and text for a blog entry"""
    title = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    text = models.TextField()
    date_added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

    def __str__(self):
        """ return a string representation of the model."""
        return self.title
```

This is views file
**views.py**

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect

from .models import BlogPost
from .forms import BlogPostForm
def edit_post(request, post_id):
    """ edit an entry"""

    title = BlogPost.objects.get(id=post_id)
    post = title.text

    if request.method != 'POST':
        form = BlogPostForm(instance=post)
    else:
        form = BlogPostForm(instance=post, data=request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
            return redirect('blogs:index', post_id=title.id)

    context = {'title': title, 'post': post, 'form': form}
    return render(request, 'blogs/edit_post.html', context)
```

This is edit post file
**edit_post.html**

```
{extends 'blogs/base.html'}


{% block content %}
  <p>Edit Form:</p>
  <p>{{ title }}:</p>
  <form action="{% url 'blogs:edit_post' title.id %}" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.as_p }}
    <button name="submit">Save changes</button>
  </form>
{% endblock content %}
```

**forms.py**

```
from django import forms

from .models import BlogPost

class BlogPostForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BlogPost
        fields = ['title', 'text']
        labels = {'title':'Title', 'text': 'Post'}
        widgets = {'text': forms.Textarea(attrs={'cols': 80})}
```

**urls.py**

```
# defines urls patterns for the blogs app

from django.urls import path

from . import views

app_name = 'blogs'
urlpatterns = [
    # Home page
    path('', views.index, name='index'),

    # To add new post
    path('new_post/', views.new_post, name='new_post'),

    # To edit post
    path('edit_post/<int:post_id>/', views.edit_post, name='edit_post'),
   ]
```

I'm using Django 2.2.6 and python 3.7.4.

I guess there is a problem with my URL patterns or with the paths of the request.

This is the error it generates

> TypeError at /edit_post/1/
>
> edit_post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'post_id'
>
> Request Method:   GET Request URL:    http://localhost:8000/edit_post/1/
>   Django Version:   2.2.6 Exception Type:   TypeError Exception Value:
>
> edit_post() got an unexpected keyword argument 'post_id'
>
> Exception Location:
>     C:\Users\nouma\Desktop\blog_folder\ll_env\lib\site-packages\django\core\handlers\base.py
>   in _get_response, line 113 Python Executable:
>     C:\Users\nouma\Desktop\blog_folder\ll_env\Scripts\python.exe Python
>   Version:  3.7.4
>   **

Comment: Can you give `forms.py` as well? You can remove `base.html`, `index.html` codes

Comment: I have updated the question. Please review it now @pissall

Comment: show your urls.py code

Comment: I agree that the `urls.py` is key here. It seems likely that you used the name `post_id` in your URL, but called it `blog_id` in the view function. If you make them the same it should fix this.

Comment: @RobinZigmond It somehow solved the problem but now I'm having following error  **AttributeError at /edit_post/2/

'str' object has no attribute '_meta'

Request Method:  GET
Request URL:  http://localhost:8000/edit_post/2/
Django Version:  2.2.6
Exception Type:  AttributeError
Exception Value:  

'str' object has no attribute '_meta'**

Comment: **I have now updated my question**

Comment: You're passing `post` as the `instance` argument, but you've defined it as a string - the value of the `text` attribute. If you need this as a separate variable then call it something else so that `post` remains as the actual model instance that the form needs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've got my answer. The problem was that in views file I was giving unnecessary argument.
i-e
   return redirect('blogs:index', post_id=title.id)
this second argument was not needed